# Can't get n of m pages in R Markdown to work - Any suggestions please?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to get the n of m pages to work in R markdown but am stuck so any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

I have set up my document so far as follows, and this works fine - creates the .pdf with the font I want to use etc.

```
---
title: "********************"
author: "******************"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \setmainfont{Arial}
  - \usepackage{geometry}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \fancyhf{}
  - \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
bibliography: ***********.bib
csl: https:***********************
```

It seems, that it is ignoring the -\fancyfoot... line because the output is the same when I comment this line out.  I know I am missing something, but have run out of ideas and things to search for.

I hope someone can see what I am doing wrong.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by adding the following line after the

```
---
# setup instructions
---
\rfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} }
```